# R relational graph

Tags: arrays, r, plot, cluster-analysis

I have 2 arrays in R. One is called clusters with length 192 and the other is called minPts_num with length 6.

I want to generate a plot that each minPts_num of total 6 (x line) will have 6 points (above, e.g y line) of the array clusters.

```
for example: minPts_num [1] --> clusters [1:6]
next         minPts_num [2] --> clusters [7:12]
.
.
.
             minPts_num [6] --> clusters [186:192]
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe it is 32 "clusters" for each "minPts_num"? It's not much clear but are you looking for `plot(rep(minPts_num, each = 6), clusters)`?

Comment: I get the error: "Error in xy.coords(x,y,xlabel,ylabel,log): x and y lengths differ. I want to have for 1 element in x axis 6 elements in y. For the 2 element in x axis (minPts_num) the next 6 elements in y (clusters). Thats it.

Comment: If "minPts_num" is of length 6, then "clusters" should be of length 6*6 otherwise "clusters" will always differ in length hence the error.

Comment: yes I did it alreader.It works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Without providing more information, I can only infer so much as to what your data structure is.

As suggested by @alexis_laz something as simple as `plot(rep(minPts_num, each = 6), clusters)` may be what you're looking for.

However, I'm providing this longer example that is a bit different, and may be what you needed:

```
groups <- cut(1:192, (192/6))
plot(minPts_num[1], clusters[groups==groups[1]], ylim=range(clusters), xlim=range(minPts_num))
for(i in 2:length(groups)){
    plot(minPts_num[i], clusters[groups==groups[i]])
}
```